# Repairing damaged marble veneer in kitchen

Tags: repair, veneer

My kitchen counter has developed a 2cm wide bubble of the top layer of veneer. I've not really seen anything like this before and don't really know how to go about performing a fix; picture is attached.

[image: The bubble of Veneer]

I got a quote from a company and they were asking for over £300 which seems ludicrous, so I'd like to explore other options. Obviously it's not going to be possible to 100% match the repair to the original markings, but I'd like something that looks okay.

Comment: What is this material? It is obviously not marble - is it some kind of plastic?

Comment: It's some sort of plastic veneer sheeting- actually false granite not marble. I think it's this https://www.diy.com/departments/38mm-ebony-granite-black-gloss-stone-effect-round-edge-laminate-worktop-l-3m-d-600mm/38359_BQ.prd

Answer (score 1):

You could carefully drill a small hole from below, into the bubble. Then make a small slit in the bubble with a fresh razor. Get some five minute epoxy into the bubble via the slit, then use a vacuum to apply suction to the hole you drilled while gently pressing down on the bubble. Maybe have a putty knife handy for pressing and smoothing. With a little luck it may stay down flat. It’s already messed up, so you won’t make it any worse!

Also - that looks like the result of a manufacturing defect. You might contact the manufacturer about a possible warranty claim as a first measure.